# Dynamically modify web.config files with Wix Installer based on User Input

Tags: wix

I am using WiX to deploy our solution to customers. They have a choice of any combination of deploying via Checkboxes in the UI, PRODUCTION, TESTING, TRAINING. I am currently using conditions: `<Condition><![CDATA[PROD=1]]></Condition>` to have WiX process certain actions with XmlConfig.

I need the connectionStrings to be changed to have each choice added or modified to the web.config file dynamically. If only one is checked off (ideally), it will modify the current string otherwise if more than one is checked off it will add more nodes to connectionStrings

`<connectionStrings>
    <add connectionString="Data source=PROD;User Id=prod;Password=prod_testing;" name="CompanyProd"/> <!-- only one checkbox selected -->
     <add connectionString="Data source=TEST;User Id=test;Password=test_testing;" name="CompanyTest"/>   <!-- more than one is checked off -->
  </connectionStrings>`

I was using XmlFile to do this, but recently changed to XmlConfig but cannot seem to figure out how to dynamically modify/add the nodes. Perhaps I need to remove all nodes under connectionStrings first and just add everytime it finds a selection?